# REST resource design : Embedding related data VS linking to it?

Tags: caching, rest, resources

I have a REST system with Article and Author resources. Generally, when accessing an Article, I'll also want to know the Author's name. I can craft the Articles in a couple of ways to accomplish this : A) embed a copy of the author's name directly into the Article; or B) include a URI in the Article that points to the appropriate Author resource.

There's clearly a downside to copying the Author's name directly into the Article resource. By duplicating information into several resources, I open myself to conflicts between resources. After an Author updates their name, an Article resource could have their old name and an Author resource would have the new one.

Perhaps if I do not cache Articles this wouldn't be a problem? But as a practical matter, speediness and reducing the number of trips back to the server is highly desirable, so caching at the browser is something I'm shooting for.

In scenario B, linking using URIs seems correct and is much more cache-friendly. *But* this doubles the number of calls back to the server : every Article requires a second (serial) fetch of an Author. So, expensive in another way, especially if we're talking about multiple URIs to multiple other resources. When displaying 50 articles at a time, this can get crazy.

I'd like to hear how this problem is address by others. Are there "best practices" essays worth reading?

Answer (score 1):

> linking ... doubles the number of calls back to the server: every Article requires a second (serial) fetch of an Author.

REST includes cache constraints for precisely this reason, that the "second fetch" doesn't have to be made *at all* if the data is already sitting in your local cache (or can be a request that only uses partial network resources if the cache is an intermediary, or server-side). If your data can be designed in such a way to take advantage of this, you can reduce total network traffic by orders of magnitude. If it cannot, then there's no point applying the REST architectural style, which depends upon caching for network efficiency--pick a different style, like RPC.